# NotificationCompat.Builder addAction missing?

Tags: android, notifications

According to the [official documentation](http://goo.gl/Qr8IO) the  NotificationCompat.Builder class should have method addAction, however I am unable to find it (I am getting "The method addAction(int, String, null) is undefined for the type NotificationCompat.Builder")

Has anyone figured out how to access this method?

Comment: Make sure that you are using the latest version of the Android Support package. It's possible they added that method, though I thought they had not, which is why Jake Wharton created `NotificationCompat2`.

Comment: I am using the latest version (just redownloaded it few minutes ago)

Comment: Note that if you just download it from SDK Manager, that does not automatically update all your projects that are using it -- you'd still need to copy over the JAR file into the project. Beyond that, it's possible the docs are ahead of the library due to some glitch.

Comment: I added it using the menu add support library to your project in eclipse and it donwloaded it directly from the google servers

Comment: and according to the revision changelog the latest revision has "Updated NotificationCompat.Builder to support the setNumber() method.", which I have there, so I have the latest revision.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The missing methods have been added to Android support library r11.  To add it to your project you must:

1. Open the Android SDK Manager.  Scroll down and find the
   Extras/Android Support Library Package.  Check the revision column,
   if you have anything less then 11 you need to update your SDK first.
   In Eclipse that is done through the menu Help/Check for Updates.
2. After you install the Android Support Library you must manually copy
   it into your project's libs folder.  The jar is located at:

.

```
<your android sdk location>/extras/android/support/v13/android-support-v13.jar
```

Comment: While run the application it shows an error "GitVoice] Conversion to Dalvik format failed: Unable to execute dex: method ID not in [0, 0xffff]: 65536" in console

Comment: @IgorGanapolsky i just updated my lib to r20. even run `android update` on the project for good measure. I still get the missing symbol. What should i do to make the compiler find the right lib if copying it to the project folder is not an option? thank you.

Comment: @gcb  You should be using Android Studio's project structure menu.  Then go to your app module and click 'Dependencies' tab on top.  You will be able to add the needed the dependency there.

Comment: @IgorGanapolsky android studio is pain :( anyway, found in the docs that you have to either copy to your own path or leave somewhere else, compile there, and then point to it in your project.properties. so either way is fine. leaving in the tree is easier to make sure things don't change from under your feet. thanks.

Answer (score 4):

As with [revision 10](http://developer.android.com/tools/extras/support-library.html), the missing methods have been added. See [NotificationCompat.Builder](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/app/NotificationCompat.Builder.html) documentation.

Answer (score 2):

It appears the latest version of the Support Library is revision 9.  I extracted the jar file and poked around and it differs significantly with the official documentation (which claims to have been updated 26 Jul 2012 18:49) when it comes to NotificationCompat and its nested classes.