# The method setProgress(int, int, boolean) is undefined for the type NotificationCompat.Builder

Tags: android, apk-expansion-files

For the Google Play Downloader Library I'm using the Android Support Library Rev. 13 to be compatible with API 8. 
From this Support Library I want to use NotificationCompat instead of Notification.

The Google class description for NotificationCompat lists the public method setProgress(int max, int progress, boolean indeterminate) as available.

This is the part I've changed from the original Google Play Downloader Library (V14CustomNotification.java):

```
...
import android.app.Notification;
import android.support.v4.app.NotificationCompat;
...

@Override
public Notification updateNotification(Context c) {

    NotificationCompat.Builder builder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(c);
    builder.setContentTitle(mTitle);
    if (mTotalKB > 0 && -1 != mCurrentKB) {
        builder.setProgress((int) (mTotalKB >> 8), (int) (mCurrentKB >> 8), false);
    } else {
        builder.setProgress(0, 0, true);
    }
    builder.setContentText(Helpers.getDownloadProgressString(mCurrentKB, mTotalKB));
    builder.setContentInfo(c.getString(R.string.time_remaining_notification,
            Helpers.getTimeRemaining(mTimeRemaining)));
    if (mIcon != 0) {
        builder.setSmallIcon(mIcon);
    } else {
        int iconResource = android.R.drawable.stat_sys_download;
        builder.setSmallIcon(iconResource);
    }
    builder.setOngoing(true);
    builder.setTicker(mTicker);
    builder.setContentIntent(mPendingIntent);
    builder.setOnlyAlertOnce(true);

    return builder.getNotification();
}
```

Problem: "The method setProgress(int, int, boolean) is undefined for the type NotificationCompat.Builder".

All the other builder.set... are known, but not builder.setProgress.

What I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

Seems it is resolved in new version of Android Support Library, v13:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/13529155/305135

Answer (score 0):

Now I've found this: http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=30755
The methode setProgress is described but simply not included in NotificationCompat.