# The method setColor(int) is undefined for the type NotificationCompat.Builder

Tags: android, eclipse, android-notifications

I'm working on a simple project which sends push notifications.

I wanted to design my notification a bit by setting colors, icons etc.
According to Android Developer site, there's a method to `NotficationCompat.Builder` class called `setColor` and `setCategory`, but both give me a compilation error.

I've updated the `android.support.v4....` to the latest one, any more ideas?
Thanks in advance

EDIT: Here's a code snippet of the issue:

```
NotificationCompat.Builder mBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(context)
            .setDefaults(defaults)
            .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.icon)
            .setLargeIcon(BitmapFactory.decodeResource(context.getResources(), R.drawable.alert))
            .setColor(Color.RED) // The error is here!!!
            //.setCategory(Notification.CATEGORY_ALARM)
            .setWhen(System.currentTimeMillis())
            .setSubText("Tap here for more details")
            .setContentTitle("Care@Home Alert")
            .setTicker("Care@Home Alert")
            .setContentIntent(contentIntent)
            .setAutoCancel(true);
```

The exact error is copied to the question title.

Comment: Try the solution [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11668212/notificationcompat-builder-addaction-missing)

Comment: @Strider Thanks, but i've run into that thread before and tried that myself. still didn't work

Comment: Post the line where the error occures and what exactly lint says

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Updated:
The issue is that the support library wasnt updated to the latest version.

Comment: No sir, the issue is about that the method setColor just doesn't exist although it should....

Comment: What is the version of your support library?

Comment: I have both v4 and v13

Comment: i mean the version of the v4 library. Open SDK manager and update.

Comment: I have version 22.2 and it has this method. Checked it right now, it works.

Comment: strange...me too, let me check if I have the updated jar linked to my project

Answer (score 0):

setColor is only available in Lollipop so, you've to check OSVersion

```
 if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
Notification notification = new Notification.Builder(context)}else {
Notification notification = new Notification.Builder(context)

notification.setColor(your_color)
```

}